# Using np.genfromtext() to Split String Date Column into Two Int Columns with Week and Year

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to use `np.genfromtext()` to read a CSV into a np array. One of the columns of my data file is the "YYYY-MM-DD" date, which gets read as a binary string by the function. I want to import this column's data but split it into a column for year and a column for ISO week number, both as `int` or `float`. That data conversion will give me a homogenous array.

Currently, I am converting the binary string into a `utf-8` string which I then convert to a `datetime.date` object to apply `date.isocalendar()`. That function returns a tuple of ints `(Year, Month, Day`. However because a tuple does not match the other int and float data points from my other column imports, my array becomes heterogenous. I would like to make the `Year` int one column and the `Month` int another.

Here is what I'm trying without the split.

```
raw_data = np.genfromtxt('.../avocado.csv',delimiter=',', dtype = None, usecols = (1, 2, 3, 11), skip_header = 1, \
                         converters = {1:lambda x:dt.datetime.strptime(str(x, "utf-8"), '%Y-%m-%d').date().isocalendar()[:2],2:float,3: float, 11: lambda x: 0 if str(x, "utf-8") == "conventional" else 1})
```

Column 1 is the column with date strings.

Comment: As far as I know, `converters` can't be used to split in `csv` column into two fields or columns in the return array.  What do you get now?  An object dtype field with tuple values?

Comment: show a simple of your data and what you want to achieve. there maybe batter ways

Comment: I ended up just copying the date column in the CSV and extracting month and week separately.

Comment: A converter can return a `datetime` object, or `np.datetime64`, but not a tuple.  A tuple produces `setting an array element with a sequence` error.